# Postfix, virtual aliases and UTF8

Tags: postfix, utf-8

The Postfix documentation reads

> By default, Postfix sets the "SMTPUTF8 requested" flag only on address verification probes and on Postfix sendmail submissions that contain UTF-8 in the sender address, UTF-8 in a recipient address, or UTF-8 in a message header value.

Then it states

> However, if you have a non-ASCII myorigin or mydomain setting, or if you have a configuration that introduces UTF-8 addresses with virtual aliases, canonical mappings, or BCC mappings, then you may have to apply SMTPUTF8 autodetection to all email

Does that mean with user-configurable aliases via MySQL that can have UTF8 characters, I should set `smtputf8_autodetect_classes = all`?

Comment: What you have in `mydomain` and `myorigin`?

Comment: ASCII-only, but what got me wondering was the `or if you have a configuration that introduces UTF-8 addresses with virtual aliases` part.